# Javascript, HTML : set webpage to move to an about:blank page and disable to go back (kill the page)

Tags: javascript, html

I am using JavaScript to build a webpage that needs to be expired and disables the user from having access to the webpage. I have made the webpage to run a function at the expiry that I set, but the webpage is still accessible when I click 'go back' button. The following is my code of the webpage

```
        <SCRIPT>
            function checkExpiry() {
                var now_ = new Date();
                var expiry = new Date("<?php echo $expiry ?>")
                if (now_ > expiry) {
                    window.location.href="about:blank";
                    alert("The page is expired");
                }            
            }
            setInterval(function () { checkExpiry(); }, 5 * 1000);
        </SCRIPT>
```

I get the expiry from MySQL using PHP and the `if (now_ > expiry)` works just fine. However, when the webpage is moved to "about:blank" page, I can still go back to the webpage by clicking "go back" button. How can I move the webpage to a blank page and disable the users to go back to the webpage by clicking "go back" button?

Comment: Javascript can be disabled. The client side script can be modified.

Comment: I think what Matt is trying to say is that what ever you are trying to achieve will be security through obscurity at best.